# Validate textarea on enter with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found the following JQUERY script for doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
   var val = $('textarea').val();
   var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
   if (e.which == 13) {
     if(! /\S/.test(val)) {
       validaterror.textContent = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
       return false;
     }
     validaterror.textContent = '';
   }
 });
});
```

but i would not like to work with Jquery on my site because i have a obsession on page speed and this is the single script on my site that uses Jquery and would like to translate that jquery to Javascript. Please help me in this matter.

Comment: @Teemu This is the code i already have and it's working, but it is in Jquery and would like it to convert it to javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**SCRIPT**

```
document.getElementById('textId').onkeypress = function (e) {
    var val = this.value;
    var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
    if (e.which == 13) {
        if (!/\S/.test(val)) {
            validaterror.innerHTML = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
            return false;
        }
        validaterror.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textId"></textarea>
<div id='errorvalidate'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First handle the event

```
var handleEvent = function(_obj, _execute, _eventName) {
    // Check for browser support of event handling capability
    if (_obj.addEventListener)
        _obj.addEventListener(_eventName, _execute, false);
    else if (_obj.attachEvent)
        _obj.attachEvent('on'+_eventName, _execute);
    else
        _obj['on'+_eventName] = _execute;
}
```

Validate the content

```
var validate = function (){
    var obj = document.getElementById('textarea');
    var val = obj.value;
    var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
    if (e.which == 13) {
         if(! /\S/.test(val)) {
           validaterror.textContent = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
           return false;
         }
         validaterror.textContent = '';
    }
}
```

Put everything together:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
handleEvent(textarea, validate, 'keypress');
```

Comment: 1. there is a typo in `function validate`, I wrote `fuction`. 2. you should at least define an id for your textarea element. Now I try to correct your jsfiddle script, please look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/NxK2d/2/

Comment: It's echoing the message but it doesn't return false, it goes to the next line. Check it.

Comment: Because it doesn't match the regular expression. It is not clear what you really want validate.

Comment: I want to validate when user hits enter, to not let him go another row and echo a message. http://jsfiddle.net/FwMwk/1/ Just hit enter in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can replace it bit by bit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

would be like:

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") // jQuery uses an interval to check this.
```

and

```
$('textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
```

would be like:

```
document.getElementById("your_textarea").onkeydown = function(evt) {
    // do what you like
};
```

and

```
$('textarea').val();
```

would be like:

```
document.getElementsByTagname('textarea')[0].value // or give it an id and use getElementById
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

JAVASCRIPT

```
        function validateMe(obj){
           var val = obj.value;
           var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
           if (e.which == 13) {
             if(! /\S/.test(val)) {
               validaterror.textContent = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
               return false;
             }
             validaterror.textContent = '';
           }

        }
```

HTML CODE

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="5" onkeypress="validateMe(this)"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(){
 document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
   var val = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea').value;
   var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
   if (e.which == 13) {
     if(! /\S/.test(val)) {
       validaterror.textContent = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
       return false;
     }
     validaterror.textContent = '';
   }
 });
};
```